# Have okta authorization enabled app user login automatically to another okta authorized app

Tags: okta

I have two okta authorized apps in the system. If a user that is logged in to one app is presented with link to another, the ask is that the user should be seamlessly logged in automatically to the 2nd app without prompting for credentials/two factor. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, as long as you browser is capable to share 3rd party cookies. After you log into your first app, you should have an Okta session cookie which will allow you to SSO into your second app, assuming both of them are configured to do Okta SSO

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have git link to implement the use case ?

Comment: I have two different okta SPA apps running. Now if I sign in to APP 1, while signing to APP 2 it should not ask the user name and password. How do we achieve this